# List Enumeration in Python

Tags: python, list, enumerate

The snippet below is from a code tracing exercise.

```
import copy

def ct1(A, B, C, D, E):
    result = [ ]
    # 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    pairs = [(A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(A,E),(B,C),(B,D),(B,E),(C,D),(C,E),(D,E)]
    for i,pair in enumerate(pairs):
        (L, M) = pair
        if (L is M): result.append(i)
        elif (L == M): result.append(10*i)

    return result
def f(L):
    L[0] += 1
    return L

A = list(range(3))
B = copy.copy(A)
C, D, E = A, B+[ ], f(B)
print(ct1(A, B, C, D, E))
```

The part I'm confused about is the enumeration used in the for loop. From the documentation for [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) it looks like `pair` should had have values like:

```
(0, ([0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]))
(1, ([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
(2, ([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
(3, ([0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]))
(4, ([1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
(5, ([1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
(6, ([1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]))
(7, ([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]))
```

during the iteration, which means `'L'` should have values from `0` through `7` and `'M'`, the tuples `([0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2])` through `([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])`. However when I run this code through the debugger, I see both `L` and `M` are lists instead. For example, when `i = 0, L = [0, 1, 2] and M = [1, 1, 2]` and so forth. Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Read up on `unpacking`, the tuple from `enumerate()` has been unpacked into `i` and `pair`. You can nest unpacking, so you could have written `for i, (L, M) in enumerate(pairs):` without the need of `pair`.

Comment: Makes sense to me now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the line `for i,pair in enumerate(pairs):`, `i` gets the index values in the list `pairs` and goes from 0 to 9 while `pair` gets the values from the list `pairs` one by one. So for `i = 0`, the `pair` is `([0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2])`. Then you call `(L, M) = pair` and this means `L` get the first list while `M` gets the second list in the tuple. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `L` and `M` are lists. If you run

```
pairs = [(A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(A,E),(B,C),(B,D),(B,E),(C,D),(C,E),(D,E)]
for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
    print(i, pair)
```

you will get the desired result. So the tuple you are looking for is saved in `pairs`. With the line

```
# ...
(L, M) = pair
# ...
```

you split up the tuple referenced by `pair` into its elements, which are – in the first iteration – the two lists referenced by `A` and `B`.

The above line essentially means

```
(L, M) = (A, B)
```

which is equivalent to

```
L, M = A, B
```

which in turn means "assign `A` to `L` and assign B to `M`".